# Stored procedure within a select statement

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a select statement that returns x number of columns. I also have an SP that uses 3 id's that the select statement returns to give an integer result. How would I have to alter the statement below to complete this? It seems everywhere else online says to use a function, but a function only returns 1 result...?

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, y, EXEC sp_result_given_col1_col2_col3
FROM TABLE
WHERE col1 = x
```

Comment: I would convert the procedure to an inline table valued function (if possible) and use `cross apply()`.

Comment: @SqlZim -- Why would you do that?

Comment: @Hogan I was assuming OP wanted the results of the executed procedure for more than one row from a table. Not a single execution of the procedure from a single row's worth of values as parameters as per your answer.

Comment: The SP is big 30+ select statements that all return ints and then the ints are summed. I will try to convert them into an inline table, if this doesn't work I will try the cursor. This is for a query that is used to generate a report every week, so it only runs once a week.

Comment: @JohnDoe . . . From your description, a cursor seems reasonable (and I don't like cursors).

Comment: @JohnDoe -- From your description a temporary table seems possible -- but this shows -- if you don't actually put what you want in the question it is very hard to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

```
 SELECT @v1 = col1, @v2 = col2, @v3 = col3, y,
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE col1 = x;

EXEC sp_result_given_col1_col2_col3 @v1, @v2, @v3;
```

This assumes your query only gives one row result.

Multiple rows you would have to use a cursor.

> **NB:** Using a cursor in SQL often indicates a poor design